# Deleting existing name ranges using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to delete all existing name ranges from a sheet when the workbook is closed.

I am using a template with Macros to generate my main workbook. The macro is preserved in the new sheet and works fine. I have to dynamically generate dropdowns in my sheet so I use `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Name`. The problem is that, when the template is used to create another file, I am getting the exception: **`The workbook already contains this name`**

How can I clear all the named ranges to avoid this exception?

Comment: Why not using [Workbook.getName](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#getName(java.lang.String)) trying to get the name first and when this it not null, then using that name instead of creating it new? Otherwise: [Workbook.removeName](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#removeName(java.lang.String))